# Filtering is not applied to angular material autocomplete field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to use Angular material autocomplete field type. I want filter to work as I type. For some reason I cannot get it working. I tried to add **[formControl]="myControl"** to input property but then got another error (ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError).

Can you help me please?

My HTML of component:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
    <input matInput
           placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
           [(ngModel)]="inputValue"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto"
           #inputField="ngModel"
           (ngModelChange)="onChange(inputValue)"
           required>
    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="writeValue('')">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
    <mat-error *ngIf="inputField.invalid || (inputField.dirty || inputField.touched)">
      {{getErrorMessage()}}
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="createNew()">
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

and this is my TS file of component:

```
import { ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { map, Observable, startWith } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-action-input-field',
  templateUrl: './action-input-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./action-input-field.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ActionInputFieldComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class ActionInputFieldComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
// input parameters for label and placeholder of field
  @Input() label: string | undefined;
  @Input() placeholder: string | undefined;
  @Input() myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  inputValue: string = '';
  values: string[] = [];
  selectedValue: string = '';

  constructor() { }

  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]> | undefined;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value || '')),
    );
  }

  public _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.inputValue = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  getErrorMessage() {
    return 'Toto pole je povinné';
  }

  onChange = (value: any) => {
    this.inputValue = value
  };
  onTouched = () => { };

  createNew() {
    alert('create new');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the onChange method to update filteredOptions, this should update the filtered options

```js
onChange = (value: any) => {
  this.inputValue = value
  this.filteredOptions = of(this._filter(value || ''))
};
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response but it did not help. First I thought the issue is only in TS and HTML of this component but it was also in passing wrong Input to the component itself (I will answer this question)

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was with @Input(). I was passing FormControl and did not bind it with another component.

The solution to this was to add this kind of argument as an Input:

```
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
```

and then get certain FormControl from it by:

```
      this.myControl = this.form.get('Zakaznik') as FormControl;
```

I will also implement another Input argument for text in .get() method of form.